# Setting Basic Auth in client Header C#

Tags: c#, basic-authentication

I am trying to set a Basic Auth header in my code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string username = "6B562D6XXXXAC1A58E5E474B2107FFDAA66EBE94";
    string password = "FF8AFB9XXXX331CD0DF0A0C38D6ACD8502224764";

    var uri = "https://xxxxxxx/token";

    string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", svcCredentials);

}
```

This throws the following exception

> System.FormatException: 'The format of value 'Bearer Token System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine]' is invalid.'

I have tried some variations without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function `TryAddWithoutValidation`:

Something like:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", svcCredentials);
```